# reducing multiple MySQL queries by being more efficienet

Tags: mysql

Good day!

I wonder if anyone can suggest whether what I'm doing is completely inefficient - I expect it is - and suggest perhaps how I should go about being more efficient!

I extract data from a `MySQL` table and display it in a table. 
The rows of the table relate to the user and the columns are the number of entries in one of the table fields that appear between two dates.

I have 30 date ranges and therefore 30 columns.

I currently have a `PHP` array with the date ranges, and each time I loop to the next table cell, I run the MySQL query with the new date ranges. Doing this 30 times per user seems inefficient. Is there a way that I can pull it all out in one query? The date ranges are not always consecutive weeks. I may have for example, a column for

```
12/03/2017 00:00:00 - 18/03/2017 23:59:59 followed by 24/03/2017 00:00:00 - 
30/03/2017 23:59:59
```

Perhaps there's a way to pass the list of date ranges and receive back the results in 1 query? Or is what I'm doing the right way, but just slow?

here's an example of the query I currently loop with different dates inserted.

```
    SELECT * FROM `wwlassessments` WHERE `assessedBy`='STAFF NAME' && `dateAchieved`
    BETWEEN '2017-05-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-16 23:59:59'
```

Thanks for any advice. 
Jack

Comment: I think there's considerable scope for improvement beyond that suggested by the accepted answer

Comment: However, the idea that 30 date ranges corresponds to 30 columns is misguided. So, the first step is to read about normalisation

Comment: Along with the selected answer, I also added an index on the table... two fields.. the assessor and the timestamp. This had a bigger impact than changing the SQL itself. 60% time saving on drawing the data out... I'd be more than happy to hear about the considerable scope for improvement over this though :-) Thanks

Comment: Once an answer is accepted, I think it's time to move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try it:**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM wwlassessments
 WHERE assessedBy = 'STAFF NAME' 
   AND dateAchieved BETWEEN '2017-05-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-16 23:59:59' 
 UNION ALL
SELECT * 
  FROM wwlassessments
 WHERE assessedBy = 'STAFF NAME' 
   AND dateAchieved BETWEEN '2017-05-24 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-30 23:59:59'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM wwlassessments 
 WHERE assessedBy = 'STAFF NAME' 
   AND (dateAchieved BETWEEN '2017-05-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-16 23:59:59' 
     OR dateAchieved BETWEEN '2017-05-24 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-30 23:59:59')
```

Comment: The union will be really helpful as if I do a SELECT count(*) FROM .... then I'll get a new row per date range.

Comment: who is voted down my answer? Please let me know why. I'll try to improve my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Strawberry, thank you for correcting it. I copied the sql from question author.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wwlassessments` 
WHERE `assessedBy`='STAFF NAME' 
    && (`dateAchieved` BETWEEN '2017-05-10 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-16 23:59:59' 
         || `dateAchieved` BETWEEN '2017-05-19 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-24 23:59:59')
```

Also you might do some pre-checking in your `php`, to prevent duplicate date range.